# mscorlib error visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, mscorlib

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform.5.1.0' with respect to project 'StokPro', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform.5.1.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform.5.1.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform.5.1.0'
Adding package 'Microsoft.CSharp.4.0.0' to folder 'C:\Users\aras adar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Stokkk\StokPro\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.CSharp.4.0.0' to folder 'C:\Users\aras adar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Stokkk\StokPro\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.CSharp.4.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0' to StokPro
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.0.0' does not exist in project 'StokPro'
Removed package 'Microsoft.CSharp.4.0.0' from 'packages.config'
Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.0.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\aras adar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Stokkk\StokPro\packages'
Removing package 'Microsoft.CSharp.4.0.0' from folder 'C:\Users\aras adar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Stokkk\StokPro\packages'
Removed package 'Microsoft.CSharp.4.0.0' from folder 'C:\Users\aras adar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Stokkk\StokPro\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain 
any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

How to solve this problem.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem,
I installed **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform** from NuGet Manager. and it worked for me.

you can look at [missing-assemply-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607616/visual-studio-2015-c-sharp-windows-universal-app-missing-assembly-reference)
issue